# How is my source IP address for 127.0.0.1 directed traffic being altered?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I am trying to ping `127.0.0.1` from my machine with the following interfaces:

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 170879  bytes 9140807 (8.7 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 170879  bytes 9140807 (8.7 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo:1: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 192.168.117.1  netmask 255.255.255.0
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
```

I don't have any special routing or iptables rules. On ping to `127.0.0.1` I see the source ip to be `192.168.117.1` as:

```
[  +5.279957] TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:policy:2 IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=192.168.117.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=61813 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=11844 SEQ=1 
[  +0.015864] TRACE: mangle:PREROUTING:policy:1 IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=192.168.117.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=61813 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=11844 SEQ=1 
[  +0.015960] TRACE: mangle:INPUT:policy:1 IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=192.168.117.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=61813 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=11844 SEQ=1 
[  +0.015974] TRACE: filter:INPUT:policy:1 IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=192.168.117.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=61813 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=11844 SEQ=1 
[  +0.015967] TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:policy:2 IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=63078 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=0 CODE=0 ID=11844 SEQ=1 
[  +0.015690] TRACE: mangle:PREROUTING:policy:1 IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=63078 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=0 CODE=0 ID=11844 SEQ=1 
[  +0.015724] TRACE: mangle:INPUT:policy:1 IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=63078 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=0 CODE=0 ID=11844 SEQ=1 
[  +0.015613] TRACE: filter:INPUT:policy:1 IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=63078 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=0 CODE=0 ID=11844 SEQ=1
```

I have no clue who is causing the source address to change. It would be great if someone could please recommend the component I should check?

**Update:**

I wrote about the context of the problem [here](https://qasim-sarfraz.medium.com/kubernetes-v1-20-debug-story-fdef7ba01cfe?sk=e9e002e30cd301f181e2249252114d07).

Comment: There really is only one interface, the loopback, with two IPs on it.

Comment: Yes, but does that explain source IP being set 192.168.117.1? I try to remove the lo:1 interface but then the IP is set to eth0 IP address.

Comment: This isn’t as much a ping question as a question about routing and your firewall rules.

Comment: I figured out the problem, just added the answer! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out it was indeed the `iptables`. I had a container that was adding masquerade anywhere/anywhere rule but it wasn't visible on the host. The container was running `iptables` backed by `nftables`:

```
iptables v1.8.4 (nf_tables)
```

While the underlying host is still running legacy iptables:

```
iptables v1.4.21
```

Because of `nf_tables` backed `iptables` you can't see the rules configured by the container on the host unless you switch back to legacy backend before adding the rules using:

```
update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy
iptables v1.8.4 (legacy)
```

Fun stuff!